# Proving a vector identity using suffix notation

Tags: multivariable-calculus

An identity my lecturer used is:

$$\boldsymbol{ \Omega\times x\cdot\sigma\cdot n=\Omega\cdot x\times\sigma\cdot n}$$

$\boldsymbol{\Omega, x, n}$ are 3 dimensional vectors, $\boldsymbol \sigma$ is a second rank tensor. The best way of showing this is probably by suffix notation however I confused on how to order my suffixes, how do I know which are going to be subscript $i$'s, and others $j$'s and so on?

Comment: Are all of those dot products? There seem to be way too many of them

Comment: @Triatticus yes they are - remember $\boldsymbol \sigma$ is a second rank tensor and therefore a $3\times3$ matrix. Do we just go from left to right in this case?

Comment: Ah, I don't normally write dots for my tensor products hence my confusion

Comment: Well $\Omega \times x = \epsilon_{ijk} \hat{e}_i \Omega_j x_k$, is dotted with sigma to obtain $\epsilon_{ijk} \hat{e}_i \Omega_j x_k \sigma_{il}$ and finally with n to obtain $\epsilon_{ijk} \hat{e}_i \Omega_j x_k \sigma_{il}n_l$